# Python String Comparison function()

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-comparison

I am checking a piece of Python code I found online (http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/18305/), and I'm stuck over a piece of code.

To be honest I don't know Python, but I have experience in other programming languages.

The method `_computeCollisionChars` generates a number of characters and then adds them to a dictionary if they are *different*. Below is the method signature along with the relevant part for the question. **Note**: The actual code can be found on the linked source.

```
def _computeCollisionChars(self, function, count, charrange):
    baseStr = ""
    baseHash = function(baseStr) # What is this?

    for item in source:
        tempStr = ""

        if tempStr == baseStr:
            continue
        if function(tempStr) == baseHash: # What type of comparison is this?
            # logic goes here...

    return
```

My questions are:

1. What does the `function` parameter mean in the method signature?
2. Most importantly what does `function(string)` do? Why are there two
   checks, and what sort of output does `function(tempStr)` generate
   then?

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you can pass any callable object as `function` to `_computeCollisionChars`. Then `baseHash` is initialised as the result of calling `function` with an empty string as parameter. Inside the loop, the condition reads: if the result of `function` called with an empty string as parameter equals the `baseHash` do this and that. Which is kind of senseless, because `tempStr` is always `''` and `baseHash` never changes (or you didn't post that part).

In the current snippet the second `if` is never reached, because invariably `tempStr == baseStr == ''`.

As the commentors pointed out, in the real code `tempStr` and `baseStr` do indeed change and `function` is expected to be a hashing-function (but any other function which takes a string as argument should work).

Comment: _"Which is kind of senseless, because tempStr is always '' and baseHash never changes (or you didn't post that part)."_ Yeah, the actual code says `tempstr = ''.join(item)`

Comment: Yeah, in the source, `_computeCollisionChars` is called in other methods such as `_computePHPCollisionChars` and different hashing functions (`DJBX31A` for example) are passed through as `function`.

Comment: @Hyperboreus - Ok, now it does make sense :) Thanks a lot for your explanation and all the detail you've provided, and sorry if I've confused you with the empty string code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

In Python functions are first class objects, so they can be passed as arguments to other functions just fine. So `function(baseStr)` is calling the function object passed to _computeCollisionChars.

Note that Python doesn't check that it is a function object passed as an argument - it just implicitly expects this (and the program would crash it is wasn't, raising a `TypeError` exception).

```
>>> def f1():
        print "Hello world"

>>> def f2(function):
        function()

>>> f2(f1)
Hello World

>>> f2("not a callable function")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and also for the explanation and preview of how the function works and is passed around! Unfortunately Hyperboreus had a more thorough answer. As much as I'd like to I do not have enough reputation to upvote your answer. Sorry.

Comment: But I do have. +1 from me.